# CMD - Inject String into a file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I need to inject a string into the file at a given line/column position in a file, and have it overwrite any existing characters (as if the insert key was pressed in an editor). Is there a way to inject a string at a position in windows cmd?

Comment: Do you mean via a script or manually? You can use the mouse and keyboard - Move the cursor via your keyboard to where you want the string to be inserted, right click your mouse on the CMD box and select paste.

Comment: @DaveRook I'm looking to do it via a script, sorry I didn't clarify.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686261/write-batch-variable-into-specific-line-in-a-text-file) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in comments of OP:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set inputfile=variables.txt

set tempfile=%random%-%random%.tmp

copy /y nul %tempfile%

set line=0

for /f "delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do (
    set /a line+=1
    if !line!==4 (
        echo WORDS YOU REPLACE IT WITH>>%tempfile%
    ) else (
        echo %%l>>%tempfile%
    )
)

del %inputfile%
ren %tempfile% %inputfile%

endlocal
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686261/write-batch-variable-into-specific-line-in-a-text-file